# MS access 2013 add records in form if null

Tags: ms-access-2013

In a form I have two fields f1 which is select menu (combo box) and another f2 which is text box.
How to set ms access when it write a record to check if f1 is not null to get and it, if f1 is null to write the text from f2.
something like that isnull(f1,f2).

After that to insert the text from f2 to table where are listed values from f1.

Comment: Did you try some research?  **Here is a Google Search for ["write a record to check if f1 is not null to get and it, if f1 is null to write the text"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=write+a+record+to+check+if+f1+is+not+null+to+get+and+it%2C+if+f1+is+null+to+write+the+text).**  Not even kidding, look at the **first search result** (and more after).

Comment: Hi,yes of course I tried, but maybe bad research.